# Javascript location properties undefined

Tags: javascript

When I execute the follwing code in my browser:

```
for (propt in location) {
   document.write("location property " + propt + " is currently: ");
   document.write(screen[propt] + "<br />\n");
}
```

All the properties are undefined. Why does this happen?

Here is the output:

```
location property assign is currently: undefined
location property replace is currently: undefined
location property reload is currently: undefined
location property ancestorOrigins is currently: undefined
location property origin is currently: undefined
location property hash is currently: undefined
location property search is currently: undefined
location property pathname is currently: undefined
location property port is currently: undefined
location property hostname is currently: undefined
location property host is currently: undefined
location property protocol is currently: undefined
location property href is currently: undefined
```

Comment: `location[propt]`, `screen` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/), you need to wrap your `for in` loop body with a conditional statement. This is because the location properties include functions, which are coming through: assign, replace, reload, etc.

Also, you're using `screen[propt]` when you need to be using `location[propt]`.

Below is the correct code:

```
for (propt in location) {
    if (location.hasOwnProperty(propt) && typeof location[propt] !== 'function'){
        document.write("location property " + propt + " is currently: ");
        document.write(location[propt] + "<br />\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm... You are looping through `location`, but accessing properties on `screen`. Is this code you copy-pasted?

```
document.write(location[propt] +"<br />\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (propt in location) {
   document.write("location property " + propt + " is currently: ");
   document.write(propt + "<br />\n");
}
```

seems to work